# C# - How to clear out the File_Save Folder's cache of file paths

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, caching

In one of my projects, there is a need to clear out all file_Paths which are cached in the "Save As" Folder. When the "File Name" Text line got clicked it shouldn't popup any cached name. It should be plain. The problem is the folder is popping out in a Windows tool. So, I can't control that tool . It seems it is referring some cache from OS side. So, all I have to do is clearing out this cache. I dont know the location of this cache.Can anybody guide me how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what `file_Paths`, `Save_As Folder`, `file_Name Text line` are supposed to mean? Can you also perhaps show a screenshot of what you mean, as it's really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I don't know if I understood this correctly, but can't you just set the `InitialFolder` to `Desktop` or some other folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a cache, that is autocomplete for filenames of files that exist. It can only be turned on or off [per user](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/nofileautocomplete.htm), not per application.

Comment: @Thank you Codecaster. I forgot the autocompletion thing.